# Add custom field to Session Object on login

Tags: javascript, session, parse-platform, authentication, parse-server

I want to add a user-agent field to all my Session objects when a user signs in. Since the `beforeSave` CloudCode hook is blocked for Session objects, what is the right way to achieve this? Is it possible using CloudCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that from the client but it is not the best way to deal...

There are some pull request for this feature https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/4513
I hope it will be released soon

Have to try to make a beforeSave on _Session ?